# Android PList problem with XMLwise: Object/String to List View

Tags: android, plist

I'm hoping this hasn't been repeated before but I've been stuck on this for about an hour now.

I'm using the XMLwise library to parse a remote PList on an Android app. This parsed data returns a Map. The first item in this Map is the data I want, which when logged gives me this when I use **getValue()** on the Map entry:

```
[
   {
     description=Teaching at the University of Kent has been ranked among the best in the UK by the Guardian 2012 University Guide., 
     url=http://www.kent.ac.uk/news/homepagestories/university-of-kent-teaching-ranked-among-best-in-uk/2011, 
     title=University of Kent teaching ranked among best in UK} .....
   },
 // etc
  ]
```

Now I'm fairly new to Android bu that looks like an **array** of objects to me, from what I know from JSON notation. Java is telling me this is an **Object**, so I can't seem to parse this or loop through it. I'm wondering if anyone know what the best way to go about parsing this an attaching it to a ListView would be.

As a note, I've tried several different methods of parsing the Plist data and this library is first one that worked so I'm really not interested in other ways to be honest, just hoping to find out how to parse the data I've received.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to cast the `Object` to be an `ArrayList<Object>` to iterate over it, based on my reading of [the source code](http://code.google.com/p/xmlwise/source/browse/trunk/src/main/xmlwise/Plist.java).